# Sql Where, order by, having and groupby query

Tags: sql-server

Can i have an example "SELECT" query which consist of all where, orderby, having and groupby clauses....

the explanation will be helpful.

Comment: See the [MSDN documentation on SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) - it lists all the options very nicely, and has lots of examples of how to use `SELECT` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Customer, SUM(OrderPrice) FROM Orders WHERE Customer='tehlulz' OR Customer='Vijay' GROUP BY Customer HAVING SUM(OrderPrice)>1500 ORDER BY Customer
```

To break it down a little:

WHERE: is used to define conditions.

HAVING: is used because the WHERE keyword can't be used with aggregate functions.

GROUP BY: Group the results by certain fields

ORDER BY: Show the results order (like price largest to smallest)

Answer (score 1):

Summary of orders made this year by clients for clients that ordered more than $10,000 from biggest to smallest:

```
SELECT ClientName, SUM(OrderTotal) AS OrderTotal
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate >= '2012-01-01'
GROUP BY ClientName
HAVING SUM(OrderTotal) > 10000
ORDER BY SUM(OrderTotal) DESC
```

Comment: I don't see that there is a question attached here, but this might be good for the documentation, Chris. And thanks for answering my question back in February!